# Flex DataGrid column sorting has no effect

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flex3

I want to sort these associations in a alphabetic order.
Label Function is below from where the column is getting values.

```
private function setColumnLabel(item:Object, col:*):String
    {
        if(AssociationModel(item).service != null)
            return 
                    AssociationModel(item).service.serviceName
                    +"["+AssociationMoel(item).service.siServiceId+"]";           
        else
            return "";
 }



 <mx:DataGrid id="subLinearAssocGridInView" 
    width="600"
    top="30"
    left="12"
    editable="false"
    maxHeight="500"
    rowHeight="20"
    headerHeight="20">
<mx:columns>
<mx:DataGridColumn [Si_Service_Id]"
            headerText="Service                 
            editable="false"
            dataField="service"
            labelFunction="setColumnLabel"
            sortable="true"/>
</mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Here i have tried with sortabledecsending=true and sortabledecsending=true but it has no effect

```
<mx:DataGridColumn
headerText="Service [Si_Service_Id]"
editable="false"
dataField="service"
labelFunction="setServiceColumnLabel"
sortabledecsending=true
sortable="true"/>
```

And also i have tried using sortCompareFunction.

```
public function doSortForField(field:String):Function
 {
 return function(obj1:Object, obj2:Object):int 
  {
return mx.utils.ObjectUtil.stringCompare(obj1[field],obj2[field],true);
                    }


   <mx:DataGrid>
     <mx:columns>
     <mx:DataGridColumn
     sortCompareFunction=”doSortForField(‘service’)”                    
     headerText=”service” dataField=”service” />
     </mx:columns>
     </mx:DataGrid>
```

But this has also no effect. 
please suggest where i am missing . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost right, just one thing you've missed to add:

```
public function doSortForField(field:String, property:String):Function
    {
        return function (obj1:Object, obj2:Object):int
        {
            return mx.utils.ObjectUtil.stringCompare(obj1[field][property], obj2[field][property], true);
        }
    }
```

But still it won't be sorted by default - you'll have to click on column header to sort it dec/acc. See resulted code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
            creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<mx:DataGrid id="subLinearAssocGridInView"
             width="600"
             top="30"
             left="12"
             editable="false"
             maxHeight="500"
             rowHeight="20"
             headerHeight="20"
             sortableColumns="true"
             >
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn
        headerText="Service"
        editable="false"
        dataField="service"
        labelFunction="setColumnLabel"
        sortCompareFunction="doSortForField('service', 'serviceName')"
        />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>

<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;
    import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

    private function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        const mockData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {service: {serviceName: "service1", siServiceId: "serviceId1"}},
            {service: {serviceName: "service2", siServiceId: "serviceId2"}},
            {service: {serviceName: "service3", siServiceId: "serviceId3"}},
            {service: {serviceName: "service4", siServiceId: "serviceId4"}}
        ]);
        subLinearAssocGridInView.dataProvider = mockData;
    }

    private function setColumnLabel(item:Object, col:*):String
    {
        if (item.service != null)
        {
            return item.service.serviceName + "[" + item.service.siServiceId + "]";
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public function doSortForField(field:String, property:String):Function
    {
        return function (obj1:Object, obj2:Object):int
        {
            return mx.utils.ObjectUtil.stringCompare(obj1[field][property], obj2[field][property], true);
        }
    }

    ]]></fx:Script>
```

In case you want to apply default sorting:

```
 private function subLinearAssocGridInView_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        mockData.sort = new Sort();
        mockData.sort.fields = [
            new SortField('serviceName', true, true, false, null, doSortForField('service', 'serviceName'))
        ];
        mockData.refresh();
    }
```

So the resulted code will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<mx:DataGrid id="subLinearAssocGridInView"
             dataProvider="{mockData}"
             width="600"
             top="30"
             left="12"
             editable="false"
             maxHeight="500"
             rowHeight="20"
             headerHeight="20"
             creationComplete="subLinearAssocGridInView_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
             >
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn
        headerText="Service"
        editable="false"
        labelFunction="setColumnLabel"
        sortCompareFunction="doSortForField()"
        />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>

<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.collections.Sort;
    import mx.collections.SortField;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;
    import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

    private static const SERVICE_FIELD:String = 'service';
    private static const SERVICE_NAME_PROPERTY:String = 'serviceName';

    [Bindable]
    public var mockData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {service: {serviceName: "service1", siServiceId: "serviceId1"}},
        {service: {serviceName: "service2", siServiceId: "serviceId2"}},
        {service: {serviceName: "service3", siServiceId: "serviceId3"}},
        {service: {serviceName: "service4", siServiceId: "serviceId4"}}
    ]);

    private function setColumnLabel(item:Object, col:*):String
    {
        if (item.service != null)
        {
            return item.service.serviceName + "[" + item.service.siServiceId + "]";
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public function doSortForField(field:String = SERVICE_FIELD, property:String = SERVICE_NAME_PROPERTY):Function
    {
        return function (obj1:Object, obj2:Object):int
        {
            return mx.utils.ObjectUtil.stringCompare(obj1[field][property], obj2[field][property], true);
        }
    }

    private function subLinearAssocGridInView_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        mockData.sort = new Sort();
        mockData.sort.fields = [
            new SortField(SERVICE_NAME_PROPERTY, true, true, false, null, doSortForField())
        ];
        mockData.refresh();
    }

    ]]></fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sorting the `dataProvider` content instead? If you are using Array then use [Array.sort()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort()). If you are using ArrayCollection then use its [sort](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#sort) field

Comment: This is not straight forward ,since we are getting values from a labelfunction which i written in the beginning So am not getting how do i sort it , how can i set it to a dataprovider.

Comment: In that case, you can create a label property in model, populate it with string to be displayed in column when parsing data and use that to sort instead of using a label function. Here I am assuming that the value of `AssociationModel(item).service` does not change dynamically